# Broken yum package tree

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum, rpm

I tried to update OS on my EC2 instance using yum update but I get the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  * epel: serverbeach1.fedoraproject.org Skipping security plugin, no data Setting up Update Process Resolving Dependencies Skipping security plugin, no data
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cloud-init.noarch 0:0.5.14-13.amzn1 set to be updated
---> Package java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.6.0.0-44.1.9.1.16.amzn1 set to be updated
---> Package python-markdown.noarch 0:2.0.3-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-markdown-2.0.3-1.el5.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python-elementtree for package: python-markdown-2.0.3-1.el5.noarch
---> Package python26.x86_64 0:2.6.5-5.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: python26-2.6.5-5.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.3.so()(64bit) for package: python26-2.6.5-5.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtermcap.so.2()(64bit) for package: python26-2.6.5-5.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: python26-2.6.5-5.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libffi.so.5()(64bit) for package: python26-2.6.5-5.el5.x86_64
---> Package python26-libs.x86_64 0:2.6.5-5.el5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package db43.x86_64 0:4.3.29-10.9.amzn1 set to be updated
---> Package libffi.x86_64 0:3.0.5-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-17.5.amzn1 set to be updated
---> Package python-markdown.noarch 0:2.0.3-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: python-elementtree for package: python-markdown-2.0.3-1.el5.noarch
---> Package python24.x86_64 0:2.4.6-27.21.amzn1 set to be updated
---> Package python26.x86_64 0:2.6.5-5.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libtermcap.so.2()(64bit) for package: python26-2.6.5-5.el5.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: python26-2.6.5-5.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libtermcap.so.2()(64bit) Error: Package: python-markdown-2.0.3-1.el5.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python-elementtree  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm
-Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks

P.S. I'm experienced in debian based systems but not in rpm based. This is my first rpm based server so please be tolerant.

Comment: What OS are you running and which version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install required dependencies:

```
# libtermcap.so.2
wget ftp://ftp.sunet.se/pub/Linux/distributions/centos/5.5/os/x86_64/CentOS/libtermcap-2.0.8-46.1.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh libtermcap-2.0.8-46.1.x86_64.rpm

# python-elementtree
wget ftp://ftp.sunet.se/pub/Linux/distributions/centos/5.5/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.x86_64.rpm
```

Then try `yum clean all` and `yum update`

Comment: It didn't help. Output is the same.

Comment: Updated answer. It should work.

Comment: I got error messages for both packages:

warning: libtermcap-2.0.8-46.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID e8562897: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
 /etc/termcap is needed by libtermcap-2.0.8-46.1.x86_64

error: Failed dependencies:
 python(abi) = 2.4 is needed by python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.x86_64
 python-abi = 2.4 is needed by python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do.. remove python26

```
yum remove python26
```

Then update your system

```
yum clean all
yum update
```

Then if you need python 2.6 try installing it via yum

Comment: Lots of packages depends on python26 I cannot remove it.